# Is there a class or function called right before 'OnAfterDeserialize' in Unity？

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I define my class with ISerializationCallbackReceiver in ScriptableObject, and write my serialized code in `OnAfterDeserialize`. My problem is I need to do some environment preparing before OnAfterDeserialize, but `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` will call when unity startup.

Is there a class or function called right before `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` so I can add my code before unity begins to serialize `ScriptableObject`. I've already tried the `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod` Attribute but it is called after `ISerializationCallbackReceiver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a class or function called right before
>   ISerializationCallbackReceiver so I can add my code before unity
>   begins to serialize ScriptableObject.

The [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnAfterDeserialize.html) interface has two functions which are `OnBeforeSerialize` and `OnAfterDeserialize`.

You can use the [`OnBeforeSerialize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.OnBeforeSerialize.html) function to add your code because it will be called before Unity serializes your object